# Bucket with separate wall problem

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, word-problem

> [image]
>
> A bucket has total volume 2 L and 20 cm height which is separated into two equal volume side right and left by a partition in the middle.
>
> A tap water has flow rate 100 mL per second (assume that water flow to left side instantly).
>
> There is a hole at the bottom of the partition through which the water flows to the other side with flow rate given by $10\times$(Difference in height of water level in cm) mL per second.
>
> If I open a tap water at t=0 when the bucket is empty, how long does it take for the left side to be filled, and in that time how much has the water level in the right side risen to?

My Attempt:

I let $A$ to be the height of the water in the left side and $B$ to be the height of the water in the right side. So:

$$50*A'(t)=100+10*(B(t)-A(t))$$
$$50*B'(t)=10*(A(t)-B(t))$$
$$\Downarrow$$
$$A'(t)=2+\frac{B(t)-A(t)}{5}$$
$$B'(t)=\frac{A(t)-B(t)}{5}$$

To find a general solution, let-

$$A(t)=a*e^{bx}$$
and
$$B(t)=e^{bx}$$

Then, I get:

$$5*ab=1-a$$
$$5*b=a-1$$
$$\Downarrow$$
$$a=-1$$
$$b=-2/5$$

At this point, I can find homogeneous solution but don't know how to find a particular solution.
How do I proceed?

Comment: Hint: to solve the system, solve first for $A+B$ and $A-B$.

Comment: Thank you.
$$A(t)=Ct+D$$
$$B(t)=Ct-D$$
$$\Downarrow$$
$$C=2-\frac{2D}{5}$$
$$C=\frac{2D}{5}$$
$$\Downarrow$$
$$D=\frac{5}{2}$$
$$C=1$$
So, we get general solution.
$$A(t)=t+\frac{5}{2}-C_A*e^{-\frac{2}{5}t}$$
$$B(t)=t-\frac{5}{2}+C_B*e^{-\frac{2}{5}t}$$
At t=0, A=B=0, so we get
$$C_A=\frac{5}{2}$$
$$C_B=\frac{5}{2}$$
$$\Downarrow$$
$$A(t)=t+\frac{5}{2}-\frac{5}{2}*e^{-\frac{2}{5}t}$$
$$B(t)=t-\frac{5}{2}-\frac{5}{2}*e^{-\frac{2}{5}t}$$
When left side is full A = 20,
$$20=t+\frac{5}{2}-\frac{5}{2}*e^{-\frac{2}{5}t}$$
I don't know how to find t.

Comment: That seems to be correct. You need to solve the last equation numerically.

Comment: In the solution for $B$ you have a wrong sign.

Comment: @maxmilgram Thank you. B has to be
$$B(t)=t-\frac{5}{2}+\frac{5}{2}e^{-\frac{2}{5}t}$$

Comment: From wolframalpha, $t \approx 17.5023$ and $B(17.5023)\approx15.023$

Comment: I get the same result (almost; I have $B(17.5023) \approx 15.0046$). I admit I used Wolfram Alpha even more than you did, but I think what you have is about as good as you can get. Next time you have a question that goes like this I think you might add the later calculations to the end of the question (by editing it) rather than putting them in comments.